# Mongoose Model.aggregate stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Standard way of streaming appears to not work under Mongoose 4.4.2:

```
var stream = someModel.aggregate([]).batchSize(100).stream()
```

It throws both on `batchSize` and `stream`, saying they are undefined.

However the following seems to work:

```
var stream = someModel.aggregate([]).cursor({ batchSize: 100 }).exec();
```

It appears to behave in a similar way. Is this the right way to stream results from `.aggregate()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No dear, you cannot directly create a bulk/batch you have to get some wrapper/transporter like cursor (**as you already mentioned it**). And it's the right way you're doing `var stream = someModel.aggregate([]).cursor({ batchSize: 100 }).exec();`

Thanks & Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this for express to response as json
TimeTable.aggregate([]).cursor().exec().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)